# Relation between complete graph $K_N$ and it's complete subgraph $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose we have a complete graph $K_N$ with $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ vertices. Consider a complete subgraph $K_n\subseteq K_N$ from the original graph $K_N$.

Now I have a subgraph $A$ with $\{1,\ldots,k\}, k<n$ vertices. I want understand the following expression and how can we simplify this
$$
W = \sum_{A\subseteq K_N} \mathbf{1} - \sum_{A\subseteq K_n}\mathbf{1}
$$

I tried in this way
\begin{align}
W &= \sum_{A\subseteq K_N} \mathbf{1} - \sum_{A\subseteq K_n}\mathbf{1}\\
  &= \sum_{A\subseteq K_N} \mathbf{1} - \sum_{A\subseteq K_N}w(n,N)\cdot\mathbf{1}\\
  &= \sum_{A\subseteq K_N} (1-w(n,N))\cdot\mathbf{1} 
\end{align}
Is there any expression available for $w(n,N)$? Any other way of simplification is appreciated.

Comment: What are you summing over? All subgraphs? is your graph labelled, i.e. do you consider subgraphs up to isomorphism? is $k$ fixed ? could you give a precise example with $n=3$ for example ?